# NoClassDefFoundError with EncryptedDocumentException

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

I am building a java program that opens an excel document. While in the IDE everything works, when i execute the code from the built jar everything falls apart and it gives me the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException
    at com.exceltogpx.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

It stops the execution at the import of the class

```
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
```

and it's driving me crazy

it's a maven build, dependencies imports following

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I think something may be wrong with either the classpath or the way I create the build with maven, but it seems I can't find the issue itself

Comment: Maybe try removing the dependency files from your `C:\Users\<User>\.m2` directory and force them to redownload.  That has fixed a similar issue for me before.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the answer to the question
I am a newbie maven user and I had never worked with pom a before. Be sure to specify a goal for your project and to specify that it will be a "jar-with-dependencies"

[Here's the guide](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) I used to fix my pom file (I followed the second part of the guide, the one that uses Apache maven assembly plugin)

Other suggestions for others using maven for the first time. If you used any external libraries so you have dependencies, in the log you should see the download of those libs. Otherwise it means you probably did something wrong with the pom... The guide I linked works pretty good and explains what the main tags do.

Comment: any library needs to be included in the packaged TAR/WAR/etc, sometimes having automated process from the IDE or Maven can hide this details from you.